# Plot frequencies on a polar plot using angle data, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, angle, polar-coordinates

I am trying to use a polar plot to represent frequencies according to a circular angle/direction (0-360 degrees). For some reason I am having problems trying to define the scale in the plot to represent all 3 angles. At the moment only 2 are showing ("B" and "C"). Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance,

```
library(ggplot2)  

data <- read.table(text = "stat  angle  freq    perc
                   A    1   720 79
                   B    223.5017    121 13
                   C    117.9372    68  7", header=T)

head(data)
str(data)

db<-data

db$stat<-factor(db$stat)
levels(db$stat)

# Plot

bp<-ggplot(db, aes(x = angle, y = perc), fill = factor(stat)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="grey100", aes(fill = factor(stat),  
                                                  width = 16)) + 
  coord_polar(theta="x", start=0) +
  theme_minimal() + ylab("Detections (%)") +
  scale_x_continuous("", lim=c(0,360), breaks = seq(0, 315, 45), 
                   labels = c("N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW"))

bp2<-bp + theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey60", size=0.45),
                panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey60", size=0.45))
```

Answer (score 1):

Width in geom_bar is the issue. Following works:

```
ggplot(db) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           colour="grey100",
           aes(x = angle, y = perc, fill = stat, width = 2)) + 
  coord_polar() +
  theme_minimal() + 
  ylab("Detections (%)")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,360),
                     breaks = seq(0, 315, 45),
                     labels = c("N","NE","E","SE","S","SW","W","NW"))
```

[image]

Comment: The problem that I have is with setting the right scale to represent angles in the full circle (0-360) and labelling those angles as directions (e.g. "N","S","W","E", etc).

Comment: I still think there is something wrong going on. When I try other "angles" (larger dispersion from 0/360) I can use a larger width. It's strange that with this specific angle of 1 I have to adjust the width.

Comment: With value of 1 there is a problem in geom_bar also. It will work you keep the x axis values of -20 etc, which is not possible here.